# Scrubbing strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a series of strings in the following format:

```
String a = "Agregator par. L1-23 2/22.-------->EFM Actelis ML628  8-210  alternative 8-/208                                                        ";
```

As you can see, the original format doesn't look very good, so I would like to remove parts of the string to give the following result:

```
"Agregator par. L1-23 2/22.EFM Actelis ML628  8-210  alternative 8-/208"
```

Not all of my strings follow this exact format, however, which means they're not simple to manipulate.

Here's what I want to do:

- Remove all trailing blank spaces (about 56 of them, but not always the same number)
- Remove all occurrences of `-------->`, without removing hyphens from other parts of the string. The number of hyphens in `-------->` may vary between strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to remove unwanted letters.

```
String a= "Agregator par. L1-23 2/22.-------->EFM Actelis ML628  8-210  alternative 8-/208                                                        ";

     a = a.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
     a = a.replaceAll("-*>", " ");
```

`a.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ")` will remove all spaces at end and if more than one spaces are there it will replace by single space.

**Output :** `"Agregator par. L1-23 2/22. EFM Actelis ML628 8-210 alternative 8-/208"`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass regular expressions to the `replaceAll` method, so the following works:

```
String s = "Agregator par. L1-23 2/22.-------->EFM Actelis ML628  8-210  alternative 8-/208";
s = s.replaceAll("-*>", " ");
```

regexps are especially useful if you don't know the amount of `-`'es in your `----->`

Comment: thanks. but second question is how to remove those necessary blank spaces on the last places and not to remove all blank spaces in string?

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` will not remove blanks in the middle of the String...
taken from the API doc of trim() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html:

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted.

also if you do a `replaceAll("-------->", "")`

it will only replace the exact String "-------->" nothing which has less dashes or no greater than at the end.... if you cannot do exact matching have a look at Regular Expressions http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method of String like this.

```
String a= "Agregator par. L1-23 2/22.-------->EFM Actelis ML628  8-210  alternative 8-/208 ";
a=a.replace("-------->", " "); //to replace the arrow
a=a.replace("  ", " "); //to replace the double spaces
```

Result: `Agregator par. L1-23 2/22. EFM Actelis ML628 8-210 alternative 8-/208`

Comment: I can not use this because unfortunate I do not know number of lines in  --------> it can be changeable in other strings

Comment: @Dejan , then try this a=a.replaceAll("-{2,1000}", "");
  a=a.replaceAll(">", " "); which will replace all - that are more than 2 in a row.

Answer (score 0):

use split("----->") and then combine the result array

```
String [] array = s.split("---->");
String snew = "";
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   snew += array[i];
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The number of '-' in the arrow change. So you need to use regular expressions to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can:
1- use String.replace() method to replace something in your string.
2- use regular expressions to find some specific pattern in your string( like "--->" or "-->" or "--------->" or anything else)

Answer (score 0):

The StringUtils class from apache common-lang provides easy and handful operation over String,FQN org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils